# Проблема отображения названия приложения в окне UAC

Tags: delphi, windows, winapi, com, uac

Сделал как написано здесь:

http://mda-delphi.blogspot.ru/2009/03/vista-uac-delphi-3.html

http://freeweb.siol.net/aoven/SourceCode/ElevationDemo.zip

Все работает нормально, но есть проблема с отображением «friendly name» класса.
(об «friendly name» написано здесь - http://www.sandon.it/?q=node/90)

Почему-то получилось так, что юникодная строка отобразилась как будто ansi-строка.
И при том самое первое значение как бы где-то прокешировалось.
Потому как я уже несколько раз менял ресурс со строкой, пресобирал dll, перерегистрировал dll, менял кодировки строки.
И все равно отображается самая первая строка, что была при первой регистрации dll.

Например, сейчас строковый ресурс выглядит так:

```
STRINGTABLE
LANGUAGE 0, 0
{
101, "Test Test Test Test"
}

STRINGTABLE
LANGUAGE 25, 0
{
101, "test abc 123"
}

STRINGTABLE
LANGUAGE 25, 1
{
101, "test abc"
}
```

А окно запроса повышения прав все равно выводит старую строку:

[image: UAC message]

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы строка нормально отображалась и отображалась русскими буквами???

Comment: Хм. А у вас что ли ANSI-приложение?

Comment: @VladD Нет. Unicode.  У меня везде используются функции с суффиксом W.  Да и эту строку система читает сама: [The COM Elevation Moniker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms679687%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) через фукнцию **RegLoadMUIString**

Comment: Жаль, а то решение было бы простым :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Этот текст похож на русский текст в utf-8, отображенный как ansi текст.

В Windows существует т.н. MUI Cache, где хранятся некоторые строки (названия приложений) для текущего языка.

Чтобы текст обновился, мне потребовалось удалить одно значение для модуля COM-сервера в ключе реестра  (у меня windows 8):

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\MuiCache\27d\B1A07F78`

(у вас он можен называться по-другому)

Есть также программа [MUICacheView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/muicache_view.html), позволяющая вывести список закешированных названий приложений (только приложений, не dll и не com серверов).

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло! Теперь осталось разобраться с русскими символами... Да и еще бы хотелось знать почему этот кеш не обновлялся при перекомпиляции DLL.

Comment: Помогло, но все равно странное поведение. Я удалил запись в реестре, перекомпилировал dll и строка в сообщении UAC обновилась. Я потом опять удалил запись в реестре, перекомпилировал dll уже с новой строкой и строка осталась прежней. Помогла перезагрузка компа.

Comment: И, кстати, проблема с русскими буквами волшебным образом решилась